# Fast way to reset all the values in containers.map in matlab

Tags: matlab

I used container.Map to construct a map object with the code following:

```
InitialValue=1:5
mapObj = containers.Map(FullKeySet,InitialValue)
```

Now I need to reset all the values in the mapObj, which means that all the values in the mapObj should be 0, how to do that fast?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having only one reference to the mapObj, creating a new one is probably the fastest possibility:

```
mapObj=containers.Map(mapObj.keys,zeros(size(mapObj.keys)))
```